# how to insert data within a calendar cell into a database

Tags: asp.net, calendar

i have a calender and i was able to add text-box inside the cell using the day-render event but what i am trying to do is allow the user to add data to the text-box and then press add and the content is added to a database and showed inside that same text-box:

here is what i did:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
}

protected void update(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) 
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    Button1.click += new EventHandler(insert);

    e.Cell.Controls.Add(Button1);
    e.Cell.Controls.Add(textBox2);
}

protected void insert(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

}
```

and i know how to insert the data but i am lost on how to identify it and output it back to the same text box

thanks

Comment: There is a built-in AJAX control int the AJAX control toolkit to do this, FYI: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure exactly what part you are lost on based on your question, so short of providing a complete working example I'll hit some of the main points:

1) To identify the data you are inserting, attach a date (and time if applicable) to the record.  (Edit: are you looking for a mechanism to accomplish this?  If so post your current `DayRender` handler code and `Calendar` markup).

2) To populate individual day data in a calendar, use `Calendar.VisibleDate` (to filter DB results) in a `Page.Load` handler to load a data structure (such as a `List<T>`) with day data for the entire month.  Then in a `Calendar.DayRender` handler, add appropriate records from the structure to the `e.Cell`.

3) To cause the new results to show up on the first page refresh after insertion, you should be able to get away with using a `Response.Redirect` to the current page after insertion.  This will cause the page generation process to restart, but you will lose ViewState.

---

Edit: Here is a basic prototype of what I tried to describe above.  Note that you could pre-fetch into any enumerable data type, I use a `List<T>` here.

```
//Page code-behind
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<DataObject> liCurrentMonth = new List<DataObject>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        liCurrentMonth = DataObject.GetCurrentMonth(Calendar1.VisibleDate);   
    }

    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataObject item in liCurrentMonth)
        {
            if (item.date == e.Day.Date)
            {
                Literal lit = new Literal();
                lit.Text = item.text;
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(lit);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Data layer object
public class DataObject
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }

    public static List<DataObject> GetCurrentMonth(DateTime currentdate)
    {
        //Get items from the db here, based on currentdate parameter
        //and populate the List<DataObject>.
        return new List<DataObject>();
    }
}
```

Comment: but every cell has a textbox how do i insert the date for the cell that this textbox exist in if i cant use `SelectedDate`

Comment: Yeah, I see that is a problem.  AndyPeacock's point is very true, the problem is the event hooking doesn't even work, because viewstate does not hold on to the textboxes you are dynamically rendering after viewstate is established.  I don't know if I have an answer for you on that one.

Comment: can i add a textbox with a calender so the user insert some text in the textbox and then choose the date from the calender and all of that is inserted in the database(i can do that). but how do i output the text from the database to the corresponding date

Comment: I think the change you are suggesting is a good idea, but since the problem is now a lot different I would recommend you post a new question for this.  My original answer covers the basics of what you are asking for.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but to make sure i understood what you said correctly, i have to create a `datatable` or _set_ and then connect the `Calendar.VisibleDate` to the date column through the `Calendar.DayRender` handler, then i have to create a control like a `literal` within the Calendar and connect that control to the description column that corresponds to the date.

Comment: Close, but I was suggesting to use `Calendar.VisibleDate` as a parameter to pre-fetch all items for the currently visible month from the DB.  See my protoype code above.

Comment: ended up using an `sqlDataReader` with the `e.day.dat` but thank you very much for your help and pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll get this to work. Its the page viewstate that remembers the value entered into textboxes etc. Viewstate is created just before the page renders. The Calendar DayRender event is called during the calendars rendering, and hence after viewstate has done its thing. Therefore the viewstate mechanism is not aware of the existance of the textboxes and so will not track their content.

Perhaps you could assign each textbox an ID based on the month and day number, on postback you could check for this control ID in the Request.Form collection and do something with the data?